# Rendering a html table based on JSON response from my API

Tags: reactjs, json, react-redux

I need some help in terms of looping through the values of my table JSON value to generate a html table that will look like this:

```
<div>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Rows</td>
            <td>List 1 </td>
            <td>List 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>task 1, task 2</td>
            <td>task 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>task 4</td>
            <td>task 5, task 6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

So at a high level I need to loop through my rows, which there are 2 in the JSON below.
And for each row, I will have 2 additional columns in the table since there are 2 values in `table.lists` i.e. list1 and list2.

The values that are stored inside of the row cells is from the `table.data` portion of the JSON, as you can see I have the rowId's and then inside the taskId's for each listId.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../../app/hooks';
import {
  selectTable,
  fetchTableAsync,
} from './tableSlice';
import {
  DragDropContext,
  Draggable,
  Droppable,
  DroppableProvided,
  DraggableLocation,
  DropResult,
  DroppableStateSnapshot, DraggableProvided, DraggableStateSnapshot
} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

export function Table() {
  const table = useAppSelector(selectTable);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTableAsync(""))
  }, []);

  console.log('select table value is: ');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(table));


  

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Rows</td>
            <td>List 1 </td>
            <td>List 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>task 1, task 2</td>
            <td>task 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>task 4</td>
            <td>task 5, task 6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );

}
```

The JSON value for `table` that my API will return looks like:

```
    "table": {
        "id": "aecf78db-e893-40e7-8a5a-e4150cc5129c",
        "data": {
            "row1": {
                "list1": [
                    {
                        "task1": {
                            "sort": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "task2": {
                            "sort": 2
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "list2": [
                    {
                        "task3": {
                            "sort": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            
            },
            "row2": {
                "list1": [
                    {
                        "task4": {
                            "sort": 1
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "list2": [
                    {
                        "task5": {
                            "sort": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "task6": {
                            "sort": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
              
            }
        }
    },
    "lists": [
        {
            "list1": {
                "name": "List 1",
                "sort": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "list2": {
                "name": "List 2",
                "sort": 2
            }
        }
    ],
    "rows":
    {
        "row1": {
            "title": "Row 1"
        },
        "row2": {
            "title": "Row 2"
        }
    }
    ,
    "tasks":
    {
        "task1": {
            "title": "task 1",
        },
        "task2": {
            "title": "task 2",
        },
        "task3": {
            "title": "task 3",
        },
        "task4": {
            "title": "task 4",
        },
        "task5": {
            "title": "task 5",
        },
        "task6": {
            "title": "task 6",
        },
    }
};
```

Hoping someone can help with rendering the HTML using the supplied JSON.

I tried to make the JSON have the keys in arrays for quick lookups, hoping it will make lookups faster when rendering larger tables with lots of tasks etc.